# connected bipartite graph exists

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Does a connected bipartite graph $G=(X \cup Y; E)$ such that $|X|=4$,  $|Y|=3$,  $|E|=5$ exist? Is there a way to know? Thanks!

Comment: It would be good to try and draw such a graph with pencil and paper.  Then consider how to formally argue what the difficulty is.

Comment: "Bipartite" is nothing but smoke and mirrors here. You have a connected graph with 7 vertices and 5 edges. Or maybe you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An undirected graph with $n$ nodes needs at least $n-1$ edges to be connected. Any additional structural constraints (e.g., bipartite) will not decrease that requirement.

You have 7 nodes, so you need at least 6 edges. 5 will not work.

See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104787/give-the-minimum-and-the-maximum-number-of-edges-in-an-undirected-connected-grap/42600711